# Creating a file with a file name which did not exist already in that folder using objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsfilemanager, nsdocumentdirectory

I would like to create a file in documents directory with name `simpleFile.txt`. Now if this `simpleFile.txt` already exists, I want to create to another file with the same name but appending the file number say `simpleFile1.txt`.

Comment: What code do you have so far? What does it do wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a while loop for this purpose like below

```
NSFileManager *manager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
int i = 1;

NSArray *documentPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentPath = [documentPath objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *newFileName = [documentPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"simpleFile.txt"];

while ([manager fileExistsAtPath:newFileName]) {
    NSString *testName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"simpleFile%d.txt", i];
    newFileName = [documentPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:testName];
    i++;
}
```

Comment: You mean `fileExistsAtPath:newFileName` and want to initialise `newFileName`?

Comment: You still need to initialise `newFileName` with the path for the default file (at the moment you will initially test against `nil`).

Comment: @Wain Is it possible to check the number of files that contains "simpleFile" in its file name

Comment: You can get the list of file names in the directory, filter the array with a predicate and then get the count of objects in the result array...